# Paypal standard subscription with Variable amount subscriptions

Tags: api, paypal

When going through the Paypal docs it clearly mentions that 
Paypal Payments Standard supports `Variable amount subscriptions`

I have created the sandbox account for both business and customer.
created subscription button and subscribed with customer account successfully.

But couldn't find a way to initiate variable amount subscription to be debited to customer account/card.

Again also I couldn't find a way to automate this task using API for website payment standard.

Express checkout have API but that only supports fixed amount subscription as per the docs.

any direction on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check with following code, It will have option to charge 3 different amount from one subscription, you can set price - duration for each amount as per your requirement:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR_PAYPAL BUSINESS EMAIL ACCOUNT">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/wow1.php">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="NEW subscription">
<!-- First Variable AMOUNT END-->
<input type="hidden" name="a1" value="20"> <!-- SET AMOUNT -->
<input type="hidden" name="p1" value="3"> <!-- SET INTEGER VALUE -->
<input type="hidden" name="t1" value="M"> <!-- SET DAY,WEEK,MONTH,YEAR -->
<!-- First Variable AMOUNT END-->

<!-- Second Variable AMOUNT -->
<input type="hidden" name="a2" value="15"> <!-- SET AMOUNT -->
<input type="hidden" name="p2" value="3"> <!-- SET INTEGER VALUE -->
<input type="hidden" name="t2" value="M"> <!-- SET DAY,WEEK,MONTH,YEAR -->
<!-- Second Variable AMOUNT END-->

<!-- FIXED AMOUNT -->
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10"> <!-- SET AMOUNT -->
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> <!-- SET INTEGER VALUE -->
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y"> <!-- SET DAY,WEEK,MONTH,YEAR -->
<!-- FIXED AMOUNT END -->

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_subscribe_113x26.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

For more info, check [Sample subscription code](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_subscribe/). Hope it will help you!

Comment: Not exactly. what I want is like say we are a internet service provider with 100 subscribers. Now at the end of the month I want to bill them unique amount as per their usage. so recurring amount will not be fixed from month to month. Any idea how it can be implemented.

Comment: As I understand it, If subscriber choose Plan A then you will charge Amount X, if subscriber choose Plan B then you will charge Amount Y. etc... and It will change frequently month by month not fixed...   It is not possible with PayPal recurring payment..      To implement it, you have cancel old subscription and again create new subscription with customer.

Comment: The question asks for automated API way to do that. The answer is not using an API.